# How to set a static IP address regardless of interface hardware in Debian?

Tags: debian, network-interface, ip

I am using a Debian minimal OS for a small server. I want to have a storage device with full OS as a backup.  So if there was any problem I will be able to swap the HDD devices. But the hardware that I am installing the backup OS is different from the server. So I need a method to set a static IP address for the network interface regardless of different types of interface hardware.

I used an environment variable and used it in the /etc/network/interfaces file and it works for DHPC but for static IP it does not work. Here is the interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto $local_int
iface $local_int inet static
        address 192.168.111.250/24
        gateway 192.168.111.1
        dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

I used this command to store interface name in an environment variable:
`local_int=$(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep en)`

And the output of `echo $local_int` is `ens33`.

Comment: Why do you need a static ip?

Comment: Because I do not have a DHCP server on that network.

Comment: If you have a reason not to have a DHCP server, you usually have the same reason to use ZeroConf/Avahi and connect to your server as `myserver.local`. But that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you even managed to set the environment variable, having it available in your `interfaces` configuration?

However, the hardware-depending interface naming (eg. `ens33`) is a feature. Apparently you can deactivate this, and get back to the old simple naming, so that your interface name is always `eth0`. When your interfaces are always named `eth0`, independent of hardware, then you can use this in your `interfaces` file.

Personally i never had a problem with the old naming system. But apparently it can be instable if you have more than 1 NIC, which is why the new naming feature has been implemented in the first place. However, if you only have 1 NIC per server, this should be safe/stable.

I don't have a Debian installation myself anymore, so i can't test it. But the [documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames) seems to be not so complicated:

> The simple way of disabling the whole current interface naming scheme [...] is just to boot with the kernel parameter net.ifnames=0 [...]

Comment: Thanks, @Sheldon I will try this. But I have two or three interfaces on that system and I am not sure about the variable I just put it in the ```/etc/profile.d/```